# execute CMD commands using subprocess

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings /v ProxyServer /t REG_SZ /d 177.40.215.116:8080 /f")
subprocess.call("reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f")
```

I tried to run this this command using subprocess library,but it doesn't work and it doesn't give me any errors

Comment: Can you specify what error you got?

Comment: the program should change my internet connection with a proxy,when I run the program my internet connection isn't under the proxy and i can't see any errors

Comment: Have you tested this command on Cmd itself?

Comment: If the code runs without producing errors, this only means that you have a problem with your proxy settings.

Comment: when I run with the command on Cmd itself,it does work

Comment: I'm not sure about your problem and since Python doesn't raises an error, this issue could be out of Python's scope, did you check if you have administrative privilege when you ran the command? And try to run it using `sys.system` this is not the recommended way to run commands, but try to see what you get.